# A team with high solidarity

Tags: word-request

What do you call a team which has a reasonable **[solidarity](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/solidarity)** between its members/players?
The only word that comes to mind is **coherent**, which is something derived from the noun "[coherence](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/coherence)" and subsequently absolutely different with "solidarity".

For example, please imagine a soccer team which its players are quite harmonized and have a good cooperation and teamwork together. All the players know any other teammate's qualities and can easily find each other on the field. They have quite the same target and as the saying goes all play for one and one plays for all.

What adjective is used to describe such a team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say [**cohesive**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cohesive) (united and working together effectively).
It looks similar to coherent and is related ([especially in writing](https://www.uwb.edu/wacc/what-we-do/eslhandbook/coherence)), so maybe that is why you thought of it.

To keep it simple, "coherent" is something that "makes sense" under a specific context; you should be coherent when arguing, for example, but a it is not an adjective you would use for a team. I would think "solidarity" fits better with the example you provided.

Answer (score 3):

An idiom:

**They are on the same sheet of music.**

This implies:

1) they work together according to instructions
2) they are working towards the same goal(s)
3) they don't have disagreements about what to do

Comment: Hello @Patriot and thank you very much for the answer. But "to be on the same sheet of music" to me, has an exact connotation of being "coordinated". If you disagree, I wonder if you could provide me with a single word as an interpretation for this idiom.

Comment: @A-friend I agree with your interpritation of this idiom. Although it is still as good suggestion

Comment: @A-friend  You are exactly right.  You said it better than I did.

Answer (score 2):

One could use [chemistry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chemistry):

> the ability of people to have a good relationship

An example (from the source) suitable to your context:

> Building a strong team requires paying attention to team chemistry.

---

A related word is [rapport](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rapport):

> a good understanding of someone and an ability to communicate well with them

Comment: The phrase _team chemistry_ in particular is a very good fit. There are even [entire articles](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/team-chemistry-7311.html) devoted to the topic of team chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

One phrase which comes to mind very close to your description is:

> **Camaraderie/comradery** - mutual trust and friendship among people who spend a lot of time together. (Google Definitions)

Both words are interchangable:

> Comradery and its much more common synonym camaraderie come from the French word camarade, which means "comrade," and whose Middle French ancestor was also the source for our word comrade. In Middle French, camarade was used to mean "roommate," "companion," or "a group sleeping in one room." It traces to the Late Latin word camera, meaning "chamber." Comradery was formed by attaching the -ry suffix (as found in wizardry and citizenry) to comrade. [Source: M/W Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comradery#note-1)

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for an adjective. It might be worth mentioning [comradely](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comradely). (However, that seems to be more about friendliness than cohesiveness, so it's not nearly as accurate a word as your suggestion.)

Answer (score 2):

Such a team is in [**harmony**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harmony):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 a** : pleasing arrangement of parts : CONGRUENT
>   // a painting exhibiting *harmony* of color and line
>   **2 b** : AGREEMENT, ACCORD
>   // when a woman's desires are in *harmony* with those of her husband

While *harmony* is a noun, the phrase *in harmony* is often used adjectivally (it can also be used adverbially):

> The team is **in harmony**.
>   The team plays **in harmony**.

However, you can also use the equivalent actual adjective: [**harmonious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harmonious):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : having the parts agreeably related : CONGRUOUS
>   // blended into a *harmonious* whole
>   // *harmonious* medley of small vaulted chambers
>   — Norman Douglas

So:

> It is a *harmonious* team.
>   The team is *harmonious*.

And with its adverb:

> The team plays *harmoniously*.

Comment: What about "collaborated" Jason?

Comment: To *collaborate* simply means to get together and work on something. It doesn't necessitate that the people who work together are actually in sync about it. For instance, two people can get into a heated argument—or even be in constant conflict—yet still be collaborators in terms of producing something. (*They collaborated, but it wasn't a friendly or easy relationship.*)

Comment: @JasonB - Excellent point. As an example, [Simon & Garfunkel](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/event/article-5634941/Paul-Simons-insecurities-depression-life-long-feud-Art-Garfunkel.html) _collaborated_.  They may have sung in harmony, yet their relationship was [anything but harmonious](https://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/simon-garfunkels-rift-vicious-they-12408873).

Comment: Thank you very much again @Jason Bassford and +1 for the answer. One more question; do the words "**harmonic**" and "**harmonious**" mean exactly the same thing (at least here an in this specific case)?

Comment: @A-friend *Harmonic* is used more commonly in relation to sound specifically, while *harmonious* more in relation to the ease of integration between things. They can each be used to refer to the other thing, but it's not done as often.